# jQuery exception with document.ready() - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to perform some simple validation, and I'm following some instructions in the book *JavaScript & jQuery, The Missing Manual*. My code is simply this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form> form code here </form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#vaporizerForm').validate();
    });
</script>
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled exception at line 1039, column 15 in /Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js
>
> 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

If I remove the $(document).ready part, and just do this, it works:

```
<script>
        $('#vaporizerForm').validate();
</script>
```

Any idea why the $(document).ready() part isn't working?

**EDIT -- jQuery call stack and code**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT - Entire code in the view**

```
@model IEnumerable<DistributorManagement.Models.Vaporizer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vaporizer";
}
@{
    var grid = new @WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        rowsPerPage: 10);
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#vaporizerForm').validate();
    });
</script>

<form action="#" method="post" name="vaporizerForm" id="vaporizerForm">
    <div>
        <label>Manufacturer</label>
        <input name="manufacturer" type="text" class="required" />

        <label>BuildDate</label>
        <input name="buildDate" type="text" class="required date" />

        <label>Rating</label>
        <input name="rating" type="text" class="required number" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>

<br />
<h1>Vaporizer Info</h1>
<div class="webgrid-wrapper">
    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-rows",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Id", "ID"),
                grid.Column("Manufacturer"),
                grid.Column("Status"),
                grid.Column("BuildDate", "Build Date"),
                grid.Column("Rating")))
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() is old legacy stuff use $(function(){});

Comment: This book is 9 months old. That's technology for ya. I made the change and I still get the same error.

Comment: @MichalFranc, what are you talking about? That form of domready bind is still in the core and won't for a long time (if ever) be deprecated, let alone removed. Why did so many people upvote that comment?

Comment: @BobHorn, the book is not outdated. What version of IE are you using? Please make a fiddle, since this doesn't seem reproducible.

Comment: I'm using IE8. I just tried Chrome (v20) and I don't get the error. Of course, the validation isn't working with Chrome... grrrr...

Comment: @davin Make a fiddle? I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. :)

Comment: That might be tough. I'm using MVC4 and the default template has views within views. I'm wondering if I should just leave out the $(function(). When I remove it, the validation starts working in Chrome.

Comment: May be a bug in that *ancient* version of jQuery, or a bug that that version doesn't handle.  Try the latest version, 1.7.2.

Comment: @Pickle: 1.6.2 isn't that ancient, I'm quite sure that's not a bug.

Comment: @BobHorn: Is there more information about that error? Could you tell us what that content of that script line in your version is?

Comment: @Bergi I added the call stack screenshots to the question. And Pickle: I could try the latest version; I was just hoping the out-of-the-box MVC stuff would work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521312/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) helped to solve issue with script.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for the obvious answer, are you sure the file at `~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.validate.js` is ok? It is acting like that file is empty, or broken.

To check if the file is ok, navigate to that directory observe the file and open it in the editor, does it have any content.

If you take out the document ready stuff you probably need the following code to see an error:

```
 try {
   $('#vaporizerForm').validate();
 }
 catch ()  {
   alert('still have error');
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to verify that the file is ok. The validation actually works if I remove the $(document).ready() part.

Comment: err... not sure what that means, do you leave in  `$('#vaporizerForm').validate();` and it does not throw an error?

Comment: just to be clear, you probably won't see the error then if you don't wrap it in a try block.

Comment: Correct. (filler characters here, so I can leave a comment)

Comment: The jquery.validate.js file has 1194 lines it.

Comment: Removing document ready and putting in the try .. catch works gives no error?

Comment: No error. But the validation isn't working now either. I think I need to step away and come back to this later. I'm probably doing something dumb.

Comment: The script to validate had to go after the form. It's working again. And I'm not getting an alert when catching an error: <script> try { $('#vaporizerForm').validate(); } catch (err) { (err.message); } </script>

Comment: Strange, but this is 1.6.2, that was pre-promises so the events code was quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**-- EDITED --**

And put the $(document).ready(.......) in the bottom of your page.

This happens with some versions of IE, when your page is too long.... put it before the body !

Answer (score 0):

Put your validation script before the `<form>`.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vaporizeForm').validate();
  });
</script>

<form> form code here </form>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5p8E/) is a fiddle as an example.

Comment: Could you post your actual form code then? Are you locked in to using jQ v1.6.2?

Comment: No, I'm not locked into using that version. I posted the entire code form the view.