# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'fileUpload'

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I am having issues applying ajax and jquery functions to my multiple files attachment. affected part of my Code below;

```
$(function () {
        $("[id*=FileUpload1]").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Attach Files',
            'script': 'UploadCS.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'onSelect': function (event, ID, file) {
                $("#attachedfiles tr").each(function () {
                    if ($("td", this).eq(0).html() == file.name) {
                        alert(file.name + " already uploaded.");
                        $("[id*=FileUpload1]").fileUploadCancel(ID);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            },
            'onComplete': function (event, ID, file, response, data) {
                $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td><a href = 'javascript:;'>[x]</a></td></tr>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Whenever I run the application through VS2010 on IE, it stops running and it declares the issue stated in the title above. But on Mozilla, it runs but the result expected isn't coming up. I have seen several questions on this but it seems not to help. Any help?

Comment: It looks like the library that has the `.fileUpload` function is not loaded

Comment: How do I confirm that please?

Comment: Check the console section of the browser and see the files that are loaded

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.uploadify.js"></script> there are but loaded and still don't know why it breaks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script tags are not identified by the browser if there are closed explicitly..

Write up **self closing** script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.uploadify.js" />
```